# I want to select a specified set of rows then pick one random row out of those

Tags: php, mysql, random

I will be creating the following table

```
  $sql[] = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS #__GmQuestions(
  QnID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Question text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  Answer text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  QnLevel int(11) NOT NULL,
  QnPrize text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  QnPoints  DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (QnID),

)";
```

and the following table

```
 $sql[] = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS #__GmHistory(
  HsID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  HsGamerID int(11) NOT NULL,
  HsQnID int(11) NOT NULL,
  Hspoints  DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL,
  HsAnswer varchar(55) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  HsStatus varchar(55) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pending',
  HsDateCreated timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  HsPrize varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (HsID)
)";
```

The level column will have intergers of 1 - 10. I want to select a random question from questions where Qnlevel=1 and this question must not have been answered by the user before.
so I have this query

```
//SELECT GAMERS question HISTORY
$result = mysql_query("SELECT HsQnID FROM #__QnHistory WHERE HsGamerID LIKE GamerID");
$Answeredquestions = Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $Answeredquestions[] =  $row['QnID'];  
}
// I now select questions making sure the user hasent anweres them  
$query="SELECT * FROM #__GmQuestions WHERE QnLevel = 1 AND QnID NOT IN ('.implode(',', $Answeredquestions).')";
```

my big problem is that I need to select one random question out of these selected question. My db is big upto 600,000 questions I have seen some complaints about rand() on big dbs. Amy ideas how to pick only one random  question the user hasent answered yet. I am still developing and so all anwers are welcome even if it means changing my tables

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: I would use a subquery for NOT IN rather than building it from a  separate query.

Comment: I like the look of this method, but you need to test it and see if its going to work for you: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `RAND()` because it needs to search through the entire table (I still think you should time it, it might be "fast enough"); you can build a table of PKs that contain a list of *only* unanswered questions and user ids.

This second lookup table should be smaller than all possible questions. You can then get a random primary key from the lookup table and select it directly from the main question table.

The only problem with this is that you need to keep the lookup table refreshed; which can be a trigger or a scheduled tasks that can be done as per your system's usage patterns.

You can also cache the results of the a lookup such as `SELECT id, userid, answer` on the client side and use PHP's random functions to select from this list.

If you are going to do this; I suggest using an external cache so that multiple processes don't keep picking the same question out of this unanswered set.

Comment: this could be the right direction, thanks, Im trying something similar to this. Not sure if it will work. array_rand(). Im thinking to pick only IDS of unanswered questions by the user place my results in an array, pick a random key from the array, then fetch the row that corresponds to the random key.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably solve it using the following

Get a count of all the questions that the user has not answered i.e. 400,000.  Lets say count=400000

In your script get a random number between 1 to count i.e. 323875.  Lets say random=323875

Using the random number as an offset and limit 1 you can then get the a single question record.